# Two Bootloader installed in parallel (causing trouble)

Tags: linux-mint, dual-boot, boot-loader, manjaro

On my laptop (HP Pavilion) I have a Linux Mint 18 installation and I recently added a Manjaro Linux installation in parallel. To do so, I let the Manjaro installer shrink my Mint partition in order to make space for the new installation.

The problem that I am experiencing now is when it comes to booting. It seems to me as if the new Manjaro installation has installed its own GRUB (which is the boot loader/manager as far as I know) because in the BIOS I used to have two OS bootloaders to chose from (Ubuntu + Manjaro).

However, as I couldn't convince my laptop to offer me the possibility to choose between the two installations, I started messing around with the options. I noticed that when choosing the Manjaro boot loader I did get that menu to choose which OS to boot. I somehow "managed" to make the Manjaro-option in the BIOS disappear; I can still boot it through the BIOS -> EFI though.

Then I discovered that I simply had to `update-grub` on my Linux Mint installation in order for the menu to appear as desired, but although the menu itself is showing now, I can only boot Linux Mint from it. When trying to boot Manjaro I get some `kernel panic` error alongside with a `Can't claim resource 1` message and then it exits the boot (at least that's what I'm assuming because it won't do anything else).

This problem does not occur when using the boot-menu provided by Manjaro itself (I can boot both OS from there without a problem).

Now it seemed strange to me that I even have those two separate boot loaders alongside each other. I am wondering if that could cause the problem or if someone has another idea what the problem here could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally got it working!

My first attempt was to add a new boot option that will load the manjaro boot loader but this option got deleted on every reboot (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397895/boot-option-gets-deleted-upon-reboot))

The thing that did the trick for me was to run `sudo grub-install` on my Manjaro system which restored the Manajaro boot option in the BIOS that I managed to make "disappear" before.
Once this option has been restored I was able to make it the first boot option and now everything works like charm!