# Boot option gets deleted upon reboot

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot

On my HP Pavilion laptop I have Linux Mint and Manjaro Linux installed, wheras the former has been installed before the latter.

The problem is that I only have the `ubuntu` boot loader to choose so I tried creating another boot option via `sudo efibootmgr -c -w -l /EFI/Manjaro/grub64.efi -L "Manjaro"` because `sudo efibootmgr -v` did indeed only show the `ubuntu` option.
After having executed above code I reexecuted `sudo efibootmgr -v` and this is what it spit out:

```
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000,3000,2001,2002,2004
Boot0000* ubuntu        HD(1,GPT,28f41d4a-3c25-4379-8e81-7e4a28a618ca,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Manjaro       HD(1,GPT,28f41d4a-3c25-4379-8e81-7e4a28a618ca,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\Manjaro\grub64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device        RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot3000* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk        RC
```

So I thought I'm good now and I rebooted my computer. However the laptop still booted into the old boot loader and after having booted again I rechecked `sudo efibootmgr -v` and noticed that my newly created `Manjaro` option was gone.

So I'm assuming that it got deleted during shutdown or reboot (it persisted a logout) but I have no idea why and how to fix it.
One guess I have is that the boot entry was somehow invalid and therefore got deleted but I just can't see any error when comparing it to the existing (and working) ubuntu option.

So the question is: Does anybody know how to come over this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I got it working.

I'm still not sure why the boot option got deleted but running `grub-install` solved the issue for me as this added the boot option for me.

This might have something to do with the fact that I have (now) two bootloaders installed in parallel. For more infos on this see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394795/two-bootloader-installed-in-parallel-causing-trouble/398079#398079) of mine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where if the entry was named Linux it would get deleted but not other names. Fun times. One thing you can try is to disable the CSM.

Comment: Actually the legacy mode should be turned off anyways... But I'll check again